# How can I label subfigures sequentially with positive integers across figures?

Tags: numbering, subfloats

I want to label subfigures, across many figures, with sequential positive integers.

For example, the first figure may have two subfigures with label tags `{fig1:subfig1}` and `{fig1:subfig2}` and the second figure may have three subfigures with label tags `{fig2:subfig1}`, `{fig2:subfig2}`, and `{fig2:subfig3}`.

Then, when referencing these labels,

```
{fig1:subfig1}
{fig1:subfig2}
{fig2:subfig1}
{fig2:subfig2}
{fig2:subfig3}
```

would display as

```
1
2
3
4
5.
```

How can I do this using the `subfigure` package?

I didn't know how to use the `subfig` package yet. In the meantime, there is a MWE using the `subfigure` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
 \subfigure[subfigure A]{This is a figure. \label{label1}}
 \subfigure[subfigure B]{This is a figure. \label{label2}}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht]
 \subfigure[subfigure A]{This is a figure. \label{label3}}
 \subfigure[subfigure B]{This is a figure. \label{label4}}
 \subfigure[subfigure C]{This is a figure. \label{label5}}
\end{figure}

Tesing referencing labels: \ref{label1} \ref{label2} \ref{label3} \ref{label4}

Desired result: 1 2 3 4 5
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) What package are you using for the sub-figures? A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) is always appreciated.

Comment: Please add to your question a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating how you are building your subfigures.

Comment: I am not sure how to use the `subfig` package. Every example I found is not a "minimal working example". Can you point me to one?

Comment: @Martin Scharrer @Gonzalo Medina is there a MWE of the subfig package?

Comment: @Tyson: Your above MWE does not include main captions. Are you sure you need subfigures? Or do you simply want to place two or three figures side-by-side? In the latter case simple use `minipage`s which hold the figure content and a `\caption`. There can be multiple figures with captions in one `figure` environment.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer I was trying to create a minimal working example, so I removed the captions (on both the entire figure and on each subfigure) since they are not needed to make this example work. In my actual use case, I have captions on everything.

Comment: @Tyson: Having the subfigure numbers continuously doesn't make sense, which makes your question confusing. The main captions are part of format you want to achieve so it's OK to have them in the MWE. In this case they are actually important to see what you want. BTW, how should the subfigures be labeled in the figure itself? Not at all? Because using `(a)` etc. or using the continuously number doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer I am confused. I am not sure what you want from me in a MWE. What I want is to label the subfigures with a running counter. The reference on the _i_ th subfigure should be displayed as the number _i_. Numbering the subfigures in this way **DOES** make sense in my use case.

Comment: @Tyson: Normally subfigures belong to the figure and are independent from the subfigures of previous. The first subfigure of the second figure should be labeled again with `(a)` or `.1` or similar.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer Sure, I know I am looking for nonstandard behavoir. That is why I have asked for help here. If you don't know how to do this or don't think it is possible, would you mind deleting your answer? This page is getting hard to navigate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disconnect the subfigure counter from the figure counter.  This can be best done using the `chngcntr` package. It provides the `\counterwithout{<counter>}{<parent counter>}` macro for this and disconnects the `<counter>` from the original `<parent counter>`.

For the `subfigure` package you can use:

```
\usepackage{subfigure}% Actually replaced by `subfig`!
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{subfigure}{figure}
```

#### Update:

The above seems to work only for the sub-caption numbers but not for the references. You could add an own counter which is increased using `\refstepcounter` which makes it the target of the following `\label`.

The following code works for me. I hope it is what you want.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\newcounter{mysubfig}
\newcommand{\mysubfig}[2][]{%
    \subfigure[#1]{#2}%
    \refstepcounter{mysubfig}%
}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{subfigure}{figure}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{(\arabic{subfigure})}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
 \mysubfig[mysubfig A]{This is a figure.}\label{label1}
 \mysubfig[mysubfig B]{This is a figure.}\label{label2}
 \caption{Main caption}\label{main1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht]
 \mysubfig[mysubfig A]{This is a figure.}\label{label3}
 \mysubfig[mysubfig B]{This is a figure.}\label{label4}
 \mysubfig[mysubfig C]{This is a figure.}\label{label5}
 \caption{Main caption}\label{main2}
\end{figure}

Main figure still work? \ref{main1} \ref{main2}

Tesing referencing labels: \ref{label1} \ref{label2} \ref{label3} \ref{label4} \ref{label5}

Desired result: 1 2 3 4 5
\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Great. I updated the question with the package I am using to create subfigures.

Comment: @Tyson: About `subfigure` in general, see http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/CTAN/tex/help/Catalogue/entries/subfigure.html: "This package is now obsolescent: new users should use `subfig` instead."

Comment: @Tyson: See my update.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer This solution didn't work. The two subfigures in the first figure are correctly numbered 1 and 2, but the next subfigure in the next figured is numbered 23.

Comment: @Tyson: Without a MWE I couldn't test it myself. I will have a look on it.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer I added a MWE for testing.

Comment: @Tyson: See my updated answer. I'm not sure about the required sub-caption format. You can adjust it with the `\thesubfigure` macro as seen in the code.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer Your updated answer is close, but it changed the leading text in the caption of the subfigures. I didn't want that changed.

Comment: @Tyson: As I wrote in my last comment: You can change this using the `\thesubfigure`, e.g.: try `\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{(\alph{subfigure})}` to get the `(a)`, `(b)`, ... style back.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer I see. Well, you example works as I have requested per my MWE, but it does not work correctly after integrating into my actual LaTeX code. http://pastebin.com/AuVCLHrA

Comment: @Tyson: Note the way I used the subfigures. The `\subfigure` macros are replaced with `\mysubfig` and the `\label` is placed after, not in it. http://pastebin.com/bUFvgCJB. If this is the only application of the subfig `\ref`s it could be also solved easier.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer NVM, the problem I mentioned in the previous comment was a copy-paste error on my part.

Answer (score 1):

Not that the memoir class was specified, but in case it's useful to others, here's a MWE for multi-page figures with subfigures in memoir (I can't imagine another reason to not reset subfigure numbering when we get a new figure):

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside]{memoir}

\newsubfloat{figure}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A Chapter}
The following figure (if it had real content) would be large
enough to require multiple pages. It is made of several subfigures,
labeled (a), (b), and (c). Though we have multiple figure environments,
the \verb|contsubbottom| command treats them as part of one logical
figure.
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subbottom[First Subfigure Caption]{
        \framebox[0.9\textwidth]{Here's the content of a subfigure.}
        \label{fig:ve_uw}
    }
    \\
    \subbottom[Second Subfigure Caption]{
        \framebox[0.9\textwidth]{Here's the content of a subfigure.}
        \label{fig:ve_iw}
    }
    \caption{First Figure Caption}
\end{figure}
%
\clearpage
%
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \contsubbottom[Third Subfigure Caption]{
        \framebox[0.9\textwidth]{Here's the content of a subfigure.}
        \label{fig:ve_eiw}
    }
    \contcaption{Continued}
    \label{fig:ve}
\end{figure}
Since the previous figure has a subfigure on the top of this page,
we'll place this second figure anywhere *but* the top of the page.
\begin{figure}[hbp]
\centering
\framebox[0.9\textwidth]{Here's the content of another figure.}
\caption{Second Figure Caption}
\label{fig:second}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is not what I am asking.

Comment: is it possible to modify your answer to get the behavior I am looking for?

Comment: I'd say stick with Martin's version for now. The behavior you're looking for, as you had indicated, is very non-standard. If his reference implementation works in a MWE, but doesn't in your final document, then the real question is to figure out what other package or code is causing the difference. Starting with the MWE, start adding packages from your non-working document until the MWE stops working. That will narrow the problem down.

Answer (score 1):

The **caption** package provides `\ContinuedFloat` also for this purpose:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[subfloat]{listofformat=subsimple}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\arabic{subfigure}}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
text

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\subfloat[first]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{x}\label{f}}
\qquad
\subfloat[second]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{x}\label{s}}
\caption{A figure}\label{full}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htp]\ContinuedFloat
\centering
\subfloat[third]{\includegraphics[width=6cm]{x}\label{t}}
\caption{A figure (continued)}
\end{figure}

\subref{f}
\subref{s}
\subref{t}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @egreg Your solution does not work. See the following:
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[first]{This is a figure. \label{label1}}
\qquad
\subfloat[second]{This is a figure. \label{label2}}
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\ContinuedFloat
\centering
\subfloat[third]{This is a figure. \label{label3}}
\caption{A figure (continued)}
\end{figure}

Tesing referencing labels: \ref{label1} \ref{label2} \ref{label3}

Desired result: 1 2 3
\end{document}

Comment: Yes, it works. Of course you have to modify the way the subfigure counter is represented and use `\subref`, not `\ref`. See edit.

Comment: @egreg When I compile your example, my last line is `a b c`, not `1 2 3`.

Comment: I've forgotten the `\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\arabic{subfigure}}` line, sorry.

Comment: @egreg Normally captions of subfigures begin with a letter in parentheses. Your solution changes behavior but I didn't want that changed.

Comment: So you want (a) in the subcaption and 1 in the reference? That's absurd.

Comment: @egrg I disagree.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on Martin Scharrer's but used the subfig package (as he and others recommended).

I have (eventually) figured out how to use the `subfig` package and I really like the solution it provides for this problem. Because `myCounter` is not related to the figure or subfigure counters, everything else works (and thus looks) "normal".

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{subfig}
\newcounter{myCounter}
\newcommand{\mySubfloat}[2][]{\subfloat[#1]{#2}\refstepcounter{myCounter}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
 \mySubfloat[mysubfig A]{This is a figure.}\label{label1}
 \mySubfloat[mysubfig B]{This is a figure.}\label{label2}
 \caption{Main caption}\label{main1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht]
 \mySubfloat[mysubfig A]{This is a figure.}\label{label3}
 \mySubfloat[mysubfig B]{This is a figure.}\label{label4}
 \mySubfloat[mysubfig C]{This is a figure.}\label{label5}
 \caption{Main caption}\label{main2}
\end{figure}

Main figure still work? \ref{main1} \ref{main2}

Tesing referencing labels: \ref{label1} \ref{label2} \ref{label3} \ref{label4} \ref{label5}

Desired result: 1 2 3 4 5
\end{document}
```

[image]